# Bones no longer bend the mesh after using "X axis mirror"

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones

I **can't bend/rotate** any part without the whole mesh moving or not moving depending on the bone selected, I had each part moving before I did X Axis mirror.  When I rotate say the Head or Arm bone the mesh doesn't rotate but if I rotate the The Torso bone the whole mesh rotates.

[image: Arm]

[image: Torso]

What do I do now?  Here's what I have https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qejBuOUJzR2hQLW8/view